# apalike Bibliographystyle error with website link reference

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, apa-style

I want to cite a website link as a reference using `apalike` bibliographystyle.
I have to use apalike as requested by the conference.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[times,10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{PRADSConference}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{authblk}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\citep{lithium}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

However, The output is not numbered as the rest of references as shown below

[image]

I wrote the reference in the bib file as follows

```
@Misc{lithium,
Title                    = {Lithium-ion Specifications},
HowPublished             = {\url{http://optimum-china.en.alibaba.com/product/437274726-212297973/rechargeable_HEV_EV_bus_battery_pack_of_lifepo4_600v_500ah.html}},
Note                     = {Accessed on: 10/02/2016}}
```

I also receive this error:

```
package natbib error bibliography not compatible with author-year citations
```

when I remove the website link reference from the .tex file, No errors are there and all reference are shown in author-year style as it should be as shown in picture

[image]

Comment: If your citation should be apa like, you would get a author-year style, not a numbered one. change the content of the braket from `round` to `authoryear`.

Comment: @Johannes_B 
when I remove the website reference from the tex file, No errors are there and all reference appear in author-year style as it should be with changing 'round' to 'authoryear'

Comment: @Johannes_B 
The error appears when I put the reference as I wrote in my question.

Comment: @Johannes_B - It turns out the `natbib`-generated error is somewhat less than helpful. (But then, many TeX and LaTeX error messages aren't particularly helpful...) Fundamentally, the problem arises because the entry is lacking both an `author` and a `year` field; hence, `natbib` issues a (misleading) warning.

Comment: You should be loading `url` *before* `hyperref`, and both of these packages should be loaded after `authblk`, `natbib`, and `amsmath` -- but also before `cleveref`.

Comment: @Mico
Is the order matter ?????

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam - In the case of `url`, `hyperref`, and `cleveref`, the anwer is, *most definitely*. Incidentally, you should be setting the option `hyphens` when loading the `url` package. Give it a try, and I think you'll notice a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

The `apalike` bibliography style is designed to create authoryear-style citation call-outs. However, the `lithium` entry is lacking both the `author` field and the `year` field. What is poor `natbib` -- at heart a citation management package -- supposed to do?

I suggest you create suitable `author` and `year` fields for the `lithium` entry, delete all aux files, and recompile your document fully (LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.